# C:strncpy causing problems with pointer

Tags: c, pointers, strncpy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

I want to replace a word in a string. Here is the code

```
char text[] = "This is a list of lists";
char *find = "list";
char* pos = NULL;
pos = strstr(text,find);
strncpy(pos,"test",4)
```

This works fine but

```
char *text = "This is a list of lists";
char *find = "list";
char* pos = NULL;
pos = strstr(text,find);
strncpy(pos,"test",4)
```

This gives a segmentation fault.

In the first example "text" is an array and the data is just copied at that location. In the 2nd one "text" is a pointer. What is issue?

Comment: AHHH! You're modifying a string literal. Head for cover! Hang on while I find a dupe.

Comment: The string literal is still located in my memory.Should i not be able to change it?

Comment: Read the dupe that I linked. It has a very clear explanation. Basically, not all memory is modifiable.

Comment: Ah yes, the daily "why do my program crash when I modify a string literal"-question. It came earlier today than yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between

```
char text[] = "This is a list of lists"; // 1
```

and

```
char *text = "This is a list of lists"; // 2
```

is that, in (1), `text` is a **non-constant** array of characters; where as in (2), `text` points to a string literal, and string literals are are **constant**. You can't modify constant objects, which you're trying in (2). What you're doing in (2) in actually undefined behaviour.

Comment: Does C allow for changing the literals somehow?

Comment: @MPJ: i don't think C standard allows it. literals are supposed to be constant and you're not supposed to modify it. but your compiler may have some flag that may allow it. i don't see any reason you need to modify constant object though. you can `strcpy` any string literal to a character array and then modify the array as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the string in the second example is a string literal, which must remain constant. When you try to write on that string you are writing to read-only memory, which (depending on the operating system) is not allowed.